# Other examples of a "standard compactness argument"?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

By a "standard compactness argument" I mean a proof where one has two families $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ and $(V_i)_{i \in I}$ in a topological space, obtains *finite* subfamilies $(U_j)_{j \in J}$ and $(V_j)_{j \in J}$ of those families, and finally takes $U = \bigcup_{j \in J} U_j$ and $V = \bigcap_{j \in J} V_j$.

That argument is used in the proofs of these two well-know results:

1. A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.
2. The product of two compact spaces is itself compact.

What other results use the same argument? (Well-known results would be preferable.)

*Note:* I am *not* asking for the actual proofs — just mention of results whose proofs use that argument.

Comment: There are many "standard compactness arguments."  Therefore, your title is a bit misleading.  You might considering changing it to "...examples of this compactness argument."

Comment: Closed sets of Hausdorff spaces are not always compact.

Comment: @WilliamElliot . I think that what he meant to say is that compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: sorry - now corrected to what I had intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More very useful facts proved by such standard compactness arguments:

The closed subspace of a compact space is compact, is another type of argument (namely easier: we just add $X\setminus A$ to a cover of $A$), but what *is* an argument as you mean is the partial converse: if $A$ is a subspace of a Hausdorff space and $A$ is compact (in the subspace topology) then $A$ is closed in $X$.

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a perfect map (i.e. surjective, continuous, closed and for every $y \in Y$, $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is compact.). Then for every $K \subseteq Y$ compact, $f^{-1}[K]$ is compact.

If $Y$ is compact then, for every space $X$, the projection function $\pi_X : X \times Y \to X$ is a closed map.

Comment: I was looking for further examples of the particular type of "standard compactness argument" I indicated. The last result, about the projection being a closed map, is indeed a good example of the cited "standard compactness argument"; thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

> Every compact (Hausdorff) topological space $K$ is regular.

**Proof:** Let $p\in K$ and let $C$ be a closed subset of $K$. For each $c\in C$, there are open sets $U_c$ and $V_c$ such that:

- $p\in U_c$;
- $c\in V_c$;
- $U_c\cap V_c=\emptyset$.

Since $(V_c)_{c\in C}$ is an open cover of $C$ and $C$ is compact (since it is closed and $K$ is compact), there are $c_1,\ldots,c_n\in C$ such that $C\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^nV_{c_k}$. Since$$\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n U_{c_k}\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nV_{c_k}\right)=\emptyset$$we have two open sets ($\bigcap_{k=1}^n U_{c_k}$ and $\bigcup_{k=1}^nV_{c_k}$) such that $p$ belongs to the first one, $C$ is a subset of the second one and whose intersection is empty.

It is now easy to prove that $K$ is in fact normal.

Comment: And, of course, then that a compact Hausdorff space is normal. I forgot to cite that one. My question didn't require a proof, just mention of the result!

Comment: @murray That's what I wrote in my final sentence.

Answer (score 0):

A compact Hausdorff space is locally compact, i.e. every neighbourhood of a point contains a compact neighbourhood of that point.

We can prove this with your "standard compactness argument" 
(Note that, as it was stated in the comments, authors can mean very different things when they say "standard compactness argument")

Comment: I was looking for further examples of the particular type of "standard compactness argument" I indicated. (That a compact Hausdorff space is locally compact, in the sense that each point has a local base consisting of compact neighborhoods, uses a somewhat different argument; in fact, the easiest way, I think, is by proving that a Hausdorff space is locally compact in that sense if each of its points has *some* compact neighborhood.)

Comment: I know that's what you wanted, and the proof I know uses exactly the type of argument you mentioned. Indeed going from "has a compact neighbourhood" to "has a local base of compact neighbourhoods" uses precisely your "standard compactness argument"

Comment: Does the proof you have in mind use, or repeat the proof, that a point and a compact subset of a Hausdorff space have disjoint neighborhoods? Because I think that's really the only place where one would use the "standard compactness argument".

Comment: Well they're essentially the same actually, yes